# Nested 2 level maven project not loading in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have project structure like of one module and on top of this sub-parent I have my main directory called `parent`.

`bom.pom.xml` defines version of the all child-module so that whenever it is required by the other sub-parent then it just need to import the bom of the previous one. This is working fine and producing correct artifact in Maven but it takes about 1 hour to load in eclipse with 8 gbs memory

```
sub-parent/
|-- bom.pom.xml
|-- pom.xml
|-- child-module/
|   |-- src/
|       |-- main/
|           |-- java/
|               |-- com/
|                   |-- example/
|                       |-- MyJavaClass.java
|   |-- pom.xml
```

I tried just loading without building in eclipse but then it will create issue in terms of reflecting changes of one module to another module

Comment: Your question only shows the structure, but does not contain a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that would prove that the structure is even relevant. I doubt that a nested Maven project with a single Java class would take an hour to load, whatever you mean by "to load". Please provide a minimal reproducible example and tell what you mean by loading (be exact, e.g. if you mean _to import_, say which way and with which options). Please also confirm that the software you use is up-to-date by telling the version number of your Eclipse.